# there is no properly docs for nexus 3. So seems I got problem in searching the token key

Tags: java, nexus3

is there anybody here, who has programmatically accessed the "Nexus Repository Manager 3" ? in particular I can not achieve the token key

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the use case more detailed?

**If you want to access the API**

How do you want to access the API? Via REST? Are you aware, that only Nexus Repository Pro only provides access to the REST API?

Comment: by saying pro, you mean nexus3 ?

Comment: Nexus has two different types of licensing models, first the [OSS](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss) version which is free, but does not provide access via REST API ([see here for details](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api)). The [PRO](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype) version does provide a REST API.

We are using the REST API for fetching artifacts during the continuous delivery process, therefore I could provide some help if you perhaps have more details what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Dear @saschadoemer, can you please tell me, is it possible not to use groove script for creating a nexus 3 repo, but using just java for that?

Comment: Just saw that my last reply was missing - of course it is possible. You still need an example?